# No, I'm not what football players do.

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> Here I stand before you, ready to lift you up,
> A sad frown I will shoo, as I make you say yup.
>
> People everywhere use me every day; dads especially love what I am.
> Please listen to what I have to say, your scoff and groan is my kind of jam.
>
> Yet one day you'll tell about me to others, thinking you're clever.

What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> A bad joke, maybe specifically a pun?

Here I stand before you, ready to lift you up,
A sad frown I will shoo, as I make you say yup.

> Jokes cheer you up

People everywhere use me every day; dads especially love what I am.
Please listen to what I have to say, your scoff and groan is my kind of jam.

> Bad dad jokes which make you groan

Yet one day you'll tell about me to others, thinking you're clever.

> We retell jokes to others

Plus

> the acrostic is Happy

Comment: Wow, that was fast. You could say this one is rather easy. (Struggling to come up with something witty here)

Comment: I assume the title refers to the fact that rot13(gur jbeq CHA vf bar yrggre bss sebz gur jbeq CHAG)?

Comment: @Level51, that is correct

Comment: The rot13(qnqf rfcrpvnyyl ...tebna) was the trigger